# how to run window phone app on web platform?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I just create a window phone app game. A XAP file. I need to test it on my browser. How can I do that? I just know I have test in visual studio window phone 10 SDK. But I don't know how to run my application in browser. I want to run my window app game in browser. I plan I want to host my app game just like host a website, for every one visit link and play. Not sure ASP.NET or what can host like website, or what software can host c# application, but I want to do this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you created a native Windows Phone 8 app it only runs on Windows Phones.